# Spark with Yarn: Point in providing spark-resource related parameters?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am reading through literature about Spark & Resource Management i.e. Yarn in my case.

I think I understood the basic concept and how Yarn encapsulates Spark Master/Workers in containers.

Is there any point in still providing resource-parameters such as `--driver-memory`, `--executor-memory` or `--number-executors`? Shouldn't the Yarn-application-master(spark-master) figure out the demand and request accordingly new resources? 
Or is it wise to interfere in the resource negotiation process by providing this parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark needs to negotiate the resources from YARN. Providing the resource-parameters tells Spark how many resources to request from YARN.

For executors on YARN:

1. Spark applications use a fixed number of executors (default = 2).
2. The `--num-executors` flag for spark-submit, spark-shell, etc. sets the number of executors as expected.

For memory management on YARN:

1. Set the memory used by each executor using `--executor-memory`.
2. Setting `--executor-cores` tells Spark how many cores to claim from YARN.
3. Set the amount of memory for the driver process with `--driver-memory`.

Some general Spark-on-YARN notes:

1. Use the `--queue` option if your YARN cluster schedules application into queues.
2. Spark is optimized for in-memory computation, so ask YARN for a smaller number of memory-heavy executors (with multiple cores and more memory). Be careful if you have set memory caps within YARN.

The [Spark on YARN Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) has more details.